# Transform a nested list operation into a list comprehension expression

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I am using `Python 2.7.x`

**My Problem:**

I have a list of lists as below:

```
a = [[1,3,2,8],[2,1,4,5],[3,2,4],[4,2,3,5]]
```

Now for all elements with value say 2, I wish to change them to 9, except the first value of every sublist. That is:

```
for sublist in a:
    for i in range(1, len(sublist)):
        if sublist[i] == 2:
            sublist[i] = 9
```

So now

```
a = [[1,3,9,8],[2,1,4,5],[3,9,4],[4,9,3,5]]
```

Somehow, I am not able to put this code in list comprehension mode.

Comment: Why would you want that? Your code is perfectly fine. A comprehension will recreate the whole structure - quite a waste of memory if all you need is to replace a few digits.

Comment: List comprehensions in python are beautiful and useful only when put to good use. There is no rule that every small loop should be converted into a comprehension. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
[[9 if val == 2 and i > 0 else val for i, val in enumerate(sublist)] for sublist in a]
```

Or, as @BurhanKhalid suggests in the comments:

```
[[sublist[0]] + [9 if val == 2 else val for val in sublist[1:]] for sublist in a]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3, 9, 8], [2, 1, 4, 5], [3, 9, 4], [4, 9, 3, 5]]
```

Comment: You can also `[[sublist[0]+[9 if val == 2 else val for val in sublist[1:]] for sublist in a]`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Cool, you could add that as another answer.

Comment: Its just an improvement to your solution, feel free to edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` rather then nested looping.

```
[[lst[0]]+map(lambda x: 9 if x==2  else x, lst[1:]) for lst in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [[1,3,2,8],[2,1,4,5],[3,2,4],[4,2,3,5]]
>>> [[j if j!=2 else 9 for j in i] for i in a]
[[1, 3, 9, 8], [9, 1, 4, 5], [3, 9, 4], [4, 9, 3, 5]]
```